# How to detect WindowState changes?

Tags: forms, delphi, vcl

How can I detect `WindowState` changes for a `TCustomForm` descendant? I would like to be notified at any time the `WindowState` property is set with a different value.

I've checked if there was an event or a virtual method inside the setter but I didn't found nothing for achieving my goal.

```
function ShowWindow; external user32 name 'ShowWindow';

procedure TCustomForm.SetWindowState(Value: TWindowState);
const
  ShowCommands: array[TWindowState] of Integer =
    (SW_SHOWNORMAL, SW_MINIMIZE, SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED);
begin
  if FWindowState <> Value then
  begin
    FWindowState := Value;
    if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) and Showing then
      ShowWindow(Handle, ShowCommands[Value]);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The notification the OS sends to a window when its state has changed is a `WM_SIZE` message. It's not evident from the code quote you posted but the VCL already listens for `WM_SIZE` in `TScrollingWinControl` class (ascendant of `TCustomForm`) and calls the virtual `Resizing` procedure while handling the message.

So you can override this method  of your form to get notified.

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  protected
    procedure Resizing(State: TWindowState); override;

....

procedure TForm1.Resizing(State: TWindowState);
begin
  inherited;
  case State of
    TWindowState.wsNormal: ;
    TWindowState.wsMinimized: ;
    TWindowState.wsMaximized: ;
  end;
end;
```

Note that the notification can be sent multiple times for a given state, for instance while the window is being resized or while visibility is changing. You might need to track the previous value for detecting when the state is actually changed.

Depending on your requirements you can also use the `OnResize` event of the form. The difference is that, this event is fired before the OS notifies the window about the change. VCL retrieves window state information by calling `GetWindowPlacement` while `TCustomForm` is handling `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`.

Below is an example using a flag to keep track of the previous window state.

```
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ..
  private
    FLastWindowState: TWindowState; // 0 -> wsNormal (initial value)

...

procedure TForm1.FormResize(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if WindowState <> FLastWindowState then
    case WindowState of
      TWindowState.wsNormal: ;
      TWindowState.wsMinimized: ;
      TWindowState.wsMaximized: ;
    end;
  FLastWindowState := WindowState;
end;
```